# How to test Redis without using sleep

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to create a test with Spring-Data-Redis that does a simple `save` and `find` operation but the find operation fails likely because it is still not ready to be found.  So to work around the problem I just put a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after the save(), but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

Something like

await redis.findById(xxx)

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? can you await the save() operation so that it'll be sure saved to datastore?

Comment: That's what I did in the end

Answer (score 0):

I utilized [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) to perform the check

```
    await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).untilAsserted(
        () -> assertThat(redisAlerts.findAllByServerIdAndUserId("A", 2L))
            .contains(alertOnKafka)
    );
```